# How to get ATG webservices(importFromSiebel,getJobStatus)?

Tags: atg, siebel, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

I am doing siebel_atg reference integration. Here I need to do compilation/installation on "siebelBuild.xml". In this step, 2 targets are there. one is "`all`",  another is "`all-with-ws`". But my requirement is only getting importFromSiebel and getJobStatus Webservices.

Is there way to make web services alone?

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the architect of this project. Nice to see someone using it!

As bated states, the recommended approach is to build the entire module and use only what you need to.

However, there seems to be a bit of confusion about the properties in the initialServices in the Initial.properties files wrt to the out-bound web-services (i.e. the ones ATG uses to call Siebel).

Just to clear things up:

all-with-ws builds the inbound web-services (i.e. the ones which are invoked by Siebel), and these can be found in the SiebelWS sub module. Running 'all' won't build this sub-module.

WRT the initialServices, the components referenced in those properties files (ABOWebService, etc) refer to a Web Service pooling mechanism. If you drill into the referenced components, you'll see references to PortPool components, the purpose of which is to create an initial pool of WS port stub objects during server startup (as the instantiation of them at run-time is very expensive). Removing these won't stop the out-bound web-service objects from being generated & compiled (indeed we need the generated source to build the project).

My recommendation is to build all-with-ws and only use the parts of the project you are interested in by extension of the module to customise it. As was stated, changing the Reference Implementation code will make upgrading a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you very much, But I have Done the all-with-ws and getting an error kindly check and advise [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476992/error-on-reference-integration-atg-siebel]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876020/wsdl-creation-in-siebel, Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Commerce and Siebel Reference application is in the standard OC module format with the source code include.  As far as I see it you have two options:

1. Figure out all the code dependencies and delete and code and configurations which we won't be using **(not recommended)**
2. Use the module as is and disable the web services you are not going to use. **(recommended approach)**

The reason i recommend  **option 2** is because:

- It does not invalidate support from Oracle
- If in future you want to use other web services all you have to do is enable them
- Upgrades to the Oracle Commerce will be easier

Extract from Oracle Support Statement:

> Oracle will not provide support for changes, customizations or extensions made to the Oracle Commerce /Siebel Reference Integration Pack code, or for any implementation issues that arise from such changes.

Below is the `/config/atg/Initial.properties` from the Oracle Commerce and Siebel Integration reference application for version 11.1.1:

```
initialServices+=\
    /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/StructuredProductUIRepository,\
    /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/StructuredProductUITools,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/ABOWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/CatalogWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/ProductConfigurator,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/OrderWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/OrderDetailWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/PromotionWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/QuoteWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/CalculatePriceWS,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/EligibilityCompatibility,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/QuotingWebService,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SelfServiceAccount_Service,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SelfServiceAccountBillingProfile_Service,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SelfServiceAddress_Service,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SelfServiceContact_Service,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SelfServiceUser_Service,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/AssetManagement,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/AssetManagementComplex,\
    /atg/siebel/integration/webservices/SessionAccessWS,\
    /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/generation/BlockGenerationService
```

You can simply remove the web services that you do not need from the this file, or alternatively override it with your own property file (assuming there are no dependencies between the respective web services)

If you are using a different version of the reference application your file might look different but the approach is the same.

Comment: As an aside, did you know that you can, in your own config layer, do, for example `initialServices-=/atg/siebel/integration/webservices/QuotingWebService`? It will remove the specified value from the list. `-=` is essentially the opposite of `+=`

Comment: @Vihung "or alternatively override it with your own property file"

Comment: Thanks for the response, my  /config/atg/Initial.properties has only 4 services /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/StructuredProductUIRepository,\
                /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/StructuredProductUITools,\
         /atg/siebel/configurator/spu/generation/BlockGenerationService/,\
                /atg/siebel/order/submit/SiebelOrderSourceSink