# Error on reference integration ATG Siebel

Tags: atg, siebel

We are integrating ATG to Siebel, we are getting an error while syncing the products from Siebel below are the error.

```
[oracle@localhost logs]$ less VodafonePub.out
**** Error      Wed Jul 20 04:41:36 EDT 2016    1469004096089   /atg/siebel/catalog/SiebelCatalogImportService  THREAD (Thread-58): Batch processing failed. Logging details with parent.
**** Error      Wed Jul 20 04:41:36 EDT 2016    1469004096090   /atg/siebel/catalog/SiebelCatalogImportService  Aborting Job after ADD/UPDATE PHASE - all repository changes will be rolled back
**** Error      Wed Jul 20 04:41:36 EDT 2016    1469004096414   /atg/siebel/catalog/SiebelCatalogImportService  SingleThreadedImportService.executeImport(): Data import was unsuccessful. Cancelling the import
**** Warning    Wed Jul 20 04:41:36 EDT 2016    1469004096603   /atg/siebel/catalog/SiebelCatalogImportController       ImportService DID NOT finish successfully
Jul 20, 2016 4:41:38 AM com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.JAXRPCServletDelegate doPost
SEVERE: JAXRPCSERVLET38: unknown port name: getJobStatus
JAXRPCSERVLET38: unknown port name: getJobStatus
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.ImplementorRegistry.getImplementorInfo(ImplementorRegistry.java:68)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.ImplementorFactory.getImplementorFor(ImplementorFactory.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.JAXRPCServletDelegate.doPost(JAXRPCServletDelegate.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.JAXRPCServlet.doPost(JAXRPCServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at atg.webservice.filter.SOAPFactoriesFilter.doFilter(SOAPFactoriesFilter.java:233)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at atg.webservice.WSDLImportFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

<Jul 20, 2016 4:41:38 AM EDT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.rpc.server.http> <BEA-000000> <JAXRPCSERVLET38: unknown port name: getJobStatus
JAXRPCSERVLET38: unknown port name: getJobStatus
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.ImplementorRegistry.getImplementorInfo(ImplementorRegistry.java:68)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.ImplementorFactory.getImplementorFor(ImplementorFactory.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.ea.JAXRPCServletDelegate.doPost(JAXRPCServletDelegate.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.rpc.server.http.JAXRPCServlet.doPost(JAXRPCServlet.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have compared the port name in other Working environment, but there was no difference.

Really stuck in this please help.

Comment: Need a lot more information to help.  Which instance of ATG is Siebel connecting to? Can the siebel instance where the job is running see the ATG instance it is connecting to? Can you telnet to the ip address and port?   Do you need to add a rule on the firewall or use a proxy server? etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import process has been kicked off, so I assume you've correctly built the SiebelWS submodule, and it's being called by SCOA. It looks like the getJobStatus WS is missing however. Did you edit the build file to leave this out? Check in the Dynamo/Siebel/SiebelWS/j2ee-apps/siebelWS.war file to see if the relevant WSDL and mappings are present.

Comment: Thank you very much this really helped.