# WSDL creation in Siebel

Tags: oracle, crm, atg, siebel

We created one webservice to fetch the full product promotion structure which is based on custom version of  SWI ISS Promotion IO
This webservice is returning 80% of the promotion structure. As the IO don’t have any Integration component associate with Relation Ship Domain it is not returning the records associated with the 
Relationship domain

### [image: Relationship Domain]

The Relationship Domain applet is associated with the BC ISS Promotion CP Structure Domain BusComp which is VBC .It don’t have any table association[Please find the sceenshot attached]
Because of this in the Integration Object level we are facing issue in establishing a relation ship with this Business component

### [image: Table assosiation]

We created an oracle ticket to check this case .The oracle team responded with the following information

[image: Oracle Suport]

The above mentioned process by oracle is a manual process of generating the complete product structure in the XML format

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using the OOTB web-services? You're trying to get the Promotion Structure at real-time, correct? The GetPromotionTemplate web-service should return the information you need.